# Tangential velocity of a parabola

Tags: kinematics, projectile, homework-and-exercises

For an experiment on the parabola motus we decided to calculate the velocity of the object thrown in three phases:

1. When the object leaves the spring that throws it (we solved it using conservation of energy).
2. When the object touches the ground after making the parabola (solved).
3. **While the object is flying (unsolved).**

For the third problem we tried to use formulas like $v=\omega r$ but we remembered that a parabola is not a circle and even if we are four we still can't solve the problem. How to do it? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the vector velocity, it's straightforward to use kinematics - if you know the velocity at the beginning, the horizontal component is constant throughout the parabola,

$$v_x(t) = v_x^0$$

and the vertical component is given by

$$v_y(t) = v_y^0 - g\ t$$

where $v_x^0$ and $v_y^0$ are the initial values of the horizontal and vertical components of the velocity, and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

---

If you just want the object's speed, the simplest way is to use conservation of energy.

In the absence of non-conservative forces, conservation of energy dictates that

$$E_{total} = E_{kinetic}(t) + E_{potential}(t) = \frac{1}{2} m v(t)^2 + m g h(t)$$

Using initial values of height and speed (or elastic potential energy in the spring), the constant total energy $E_{total}$ can be found.

Solving for v in the equation for kinetic energy, where v represents the speed (the magnitude of the velocity),

$$v(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2 E_{kinetic}(t)}{m}} = \sqrt{\frac{2 (E_{total} - m g h(t))}{m}}$$

Thus given the height of the object at any time, the speed can be calculated.

Comment: Why is the horizontal component constant along the parabola?

Comment: This is just awesome! Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it, the formula is so smooth and simple... thanks, thanks a lot @Brionius

Comment: This can't be right. The horizontal velocity could never be constant throughout the parabola, since the mass experiences a normal force that's always non-vertical. An easy paradox is to suppose the mass stops when it's going up. Your argument says that this could never happen.

Comment: In my understanding of the question, the particle is not _constrained_ to move as a parabola, it is just spring-launched at an angle so that, as a projectile its trajectory is a parabola.

Comment: Oooo man, I thought it was a particle launched from a spring and constrained to move in a parabola. I just overcomplicated stuff. Thanks @Sean !